# Get session bean from another session in Spring

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat

Is there a way in Spring I can access some session bean from another session? For example, can some singletone change data in session bean for two users, or one user's action change some data in session bean for the second user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't, and that would defeat the point of having session scoped beans. If users need to see changes across sessions, you should use a stateful singleton bean accessible to both session-scoped beans (or some other persistent store).